# Grassmann paradox weirdness

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra, superspace-formalism

I'm running into an annoying problem I am unable to resolve, although a friend has given me some guidance as to how the resolution might come about.  Hopefully someone on here knows the answer.

It is known that a superfunction (as a function of space-time and Grassmann coordinates) is to be viewed as an analytic series in the Grassmann variables which terminates.  *e.g.* with two Grassmann coordinates $\theta$ and $\theta^*$, the expansion for the superfunction $F(x,\theta,\theta^*)$ is

$$F(x,\theta)=f(x)+g(x)\theta+h(x)\theta^*+q(x)\theta^*\theta.$$

The product of two Grassmann-valued quatities is a commuting number *e.g.* $\theta^*\theta$ is a commuting object.  One confusion my friend cleared up for me is that this product need not be real or complex-valued, but rather, some element of a 'ring' (I don't know what that really means, but whatever).  Otherwise, from $(\theta^*\theta)(\theta^*\theta)=0$, I would conclude necessarily $\theta^*\theta=0$ unless that product is in that ring.

But now I'm superconfused (excuse the pun).  If Dirac fields $\psi$ and $\bar\psi$ appearing the QED Lagrangian 
$$\mathcal{L}=\bar\psi(i\gamma^\mu D_\mu-m)\psi-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$$
are anticommuting (Grassmann-valued) objects, whose product need not be real/complex-valued, then is the Lagrangian no longer a real-valued quantity, but rather takes a value which belongs in my friend's *ring*???  I refuse to believe that!!

Comment: My friend followed up with saying that these Grassmann variables are like differential forms... how do I write the QED Lagrangian in that language?

Comment: In mathematics, a "ring" (derived from "number ring") is really a number system. You aren't given division in a ring (if you have it, you have a "division ring", or if additionally multiplication is commutative a "field")...so your thinking $(\theta\theta^*)=0$ is invalid.

Comment: Also note differentiating and integrating Grassmann variables are quite different! They are *the same!* This is how you get rid of these "Grassmannian mysteries" in practice...

Comment: @AlexNelson so what does that mean about the QED Lagrangian?  Is it no longer a real-valued object?

Comment: In classical field theory $\psi$'s are of course usual complex valued fields. When you quantize you are bound to require that they satisfy anticommutation relations (for otherwise some things go wrong in quantum theory). So the "ring" is ring of operators on Hilbert space. However if you take path integral approach to quantization then you have to treat $\psi$'s as anticommuting variables so that your results agree with results of Hilbert space formalism.

Comment: Additionally, in Rings, there could be products of two non-zero numbers being zero. A simple example is even modular rings, $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$: for instance, integers in mod 4, $\mathbb{Z}_4$, form a ring with addition and multiplication, and you have e.g. $2 \cdot 2=0$ but $2 \neq 0$.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/529496/is-fermion-mass-imaginary-instead-of-real

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A *supernumber* $z=z_B+z_S$ consists of a *body* $z_B$ (which always belongs to $\mathbb{C}$) and a *soul* $z_S$ (which only belongs to $\mathbb{C}$ if it is zero), cf. Refs. 1 and 2.

A supernumber can carry definite Grassmann parity. In that case, it is either 
$$\text{Grassmann-even/bosonic/a $c$-number},$$ 
or 
$$\text{Grassmann-odd/fermionic/an $a$-number},$$ 
cf. Refs. 1 and 2.$^{\dagger}$ The letters $c$ and $a$ stand for *commutative* and *anticommutative,* respectively.

One can define complex conjugation of supernumbers, and one can impose a reality condition on a supernumber, cf. Refs. 1-4. Hence one can talk about complex, real and imaginary supernumbers. Note that that does *not* mean that supernumbers belong to the set of ordinary complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. E.g. a real Grassmann-even supernumber can still contain a non-zero soul.

An observable/measurable quantity can only consist of ordinary numbers (belonging to $\mathbb{C}$). It does not make sense to measure a soul-valued output in an actual physical experiment. A soul is an [indeterminate/variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_(variable)), i.e. a placeholder, except it cannot be replaced by a number to give it a value. A value can only be achieved by integrating it out!

In detail, a supernumber (that appears in a physics theory) is eventually (Berezin) [integrated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berezin_integral) over the Grassmann-odd (fermionic) variables, say $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, $\ldots$, $\theta_N$, and the coefficient of the fermionic top monomial $\theta_1\theta_2\cdots\theta_N$ is extracted to produce an ordinary number (in $\mathbb{C}$), which in principle can be measured.

E.g. the Grassmann-odd (fermionic) variables $\psi(x,t)$ in the QED Lagrangian should eventually be integrated over in the path integral.

References:

1. [planetmath.org/supernumber](http://planetmath.org/supernumber).
2. Bryce DeWitt, *Supermanifolds,* Cambridge Univ. Press, 1992.
3. Pierre Deligne and John W. Morgan, *Notes on Supersymmetry (following Joseph Bernstein).* In *Quantum Fields and Strings: A Course for Mathematicians,* Vol. 1, American Mathematical Society (1999) 41–97.
4. V.S. Varadarajan, *Supersymmetry for Mathematicians: An Introduction,* Courant Lecture Notes 11, 2004.

--

$^{\dagger}$ In this answer, the words bosonic (fermionic) will mean Grassmann-even (Grassmann-odd), respectively.

Comment: Ok!  So the Lagrangian is a *real* supernumber!  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the QED Lagrangian is a real Grassmann-even supernumber with a non-zero soul.

Comment: Awesome!  Now I have a question about SUSY:  The supercoordinates have the following supersymmetry transformation law: $(x^\mu,\theta,\bar\theta) \rightarrow \big((x+a)^\mu-i(\theta\sigma^\mu\bar\alpha-\alpha\sigma^\mu\bar\theta),\,\theta+\alpha,\,\bar\theta+\bar\alpha\big)$.  Does this mean the space-time part is transformed into a supernumber (with a non-zero *soul*)?  seems strange!!!

Comment: I have a follow up question you can find here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40957/

Answer (score 4):

The Lagrangian may be proved to be real but the individual factors in its terms, such as $\psi$, are neither real nor complex. They're anticommuting. There are no "particular" elements of this set of anticommuting numbers that one could "enumerate" (except for zero) and they can't appear as final predictions for observable quantities but it still makes a perfect sense to do algebra with them. A product of an even number of anticommuting variables is commuting which means that it may take particular values that may be measured and compared with theoretical predictions.

I think that I am not the only one who doesn't really understand what you're asking about but there is a chance that the answer is either in the previous paragraph or the text below:

> http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/celebrating-grassmann-numbers.html?m=1

Comment: Could you please give a reference to the proof that the Lagrangian is real? Thank you.

Comment: This is in every intro to QFT that cares about such trivialities at all. You don't need a reference because it fits here. Taking $\psi$ as Grassmann-odd operators, it's known that the Hermitean conjugate to $\bar\psi \psi$ is the same thing backwards, so the mass term is Hermitian. The same with the cubic interaction term which has a real coefficient. The kinetic term needs an $i$ to be real because the Hermitian conjugation exchanges $\psi$ with $\partial_\mu\psi$ and to exchange them back, one pays a minus sign for Fermi statistics which implies $-1$ from $i^\dagger=-i$.

Comment: I think the trickiness is in the following question: If $\theta$ and $\phi$ are two Grassmann variables, does their product $\theta\phi$ necessarily map to a complex number?  If not, what does it map to?

Comment: Let me say that I was really proving that the object, when operators are substituted, is Hermitian, which implies that its eigenvalues are real. This working with the "full operators" - with a quantized theory in the operator approach - is a convenient and reliable way to decide how to complex-conjugate Grassmann numbers etc.: one Hermitian conjugates the operators using $(AB)^\dagger=B^\dagger A^\dagger$ and uses the same results for the Grassmann numbers, too.

Comment: Dear QuantumDot, yes, $\theta$ times $\phi$ is a complex number, so the product has a value you can "name", but $\theta$ and $\phi$ separately don't have values you can "name". Here I am assuming you are talking about the most elementary Grassmann-odd variables. One could perhaps also talk about the quaternion-based Grassmann variabels, whose product would be a general quaternion, or - in QFT - Grassmann-odd operators, i.e. fermionic operators, whose product is a Grassmann-even i.e. bosonic ordinary operator.

Comment: Thanks Lubos, but if $\theta\phi\in\mathbb{C}$ and $(\theta\phi)^2=0$ (by Grassmann algebra), then that would seem to suggest $\theta\phi$ must necessarily be zero. .. something has gone wrong in my reasoning...?  (**edit:** yes, I am talking about the elementary Grassmann-odd variables)

Comment: @Luboš Motl: What you prove is that the Lagrangian is Hermitian, but that does not mean it is real. For example, $\theta+\theta^*$ is Hermitian, but that does not mean it is real. OK, there may be some ambiguity about word "real", but you'll certainly agree that $\theta+\theta^*$ is not real-valued. The same is true for the Lagrangian, as far as can I judge, and that's what bothers QuantumDot.

Comment: Dear quantum dot, $\theta+\theta^*$ is actually called a real Grassmann number, too. $\theta\phi$ may have a complex value as a result, formally, but you're still trying to give values to particular values of $\theta $ and $\phi$. The derivation that $(\theta\phi)^2=0$ is legitimate but the derivation that $\theta\phi=0$ is not legitimate.

Comment: @Luboš Motl: As I said, there may be some ambiguity about the word "real", but there is no ambiguity about word "real-valued". So while $\theta+\theta^*$ may be "a real Grassmann number", it is not "real-valued", in other words, it is not a (real) c-number. And I guess this is what QuantumDot's question is about: the Lagrangian is not a c-number-valued function.

Comment: Sorry but the Lagrangian, and especially the action obtained by integrating it, *is* at least formally a real commuting c-number. That's why it appears in the exponent of the path integral. The path integral itself is a "formal" integral in which the Grassmann numbers are integrated via Berezin integrals, and these integrals make as much sense  as normal integrals for commuting variables. The reason we can't talk about the values of the Lagrangian "for particular values of $\psi$" isn't that the Lagrangian isn't formally real; the reason is that there aren't any particular values of $\psi$.

Comment: The previous comment covers the quantum theory with Grassmann variables. Classically, all Grassmann variables must be set to zero because they're proportional to $\sqrt{\hbar}$ from the canonical anticommutator and $\hbar$ is sent to zero. Still, we may discuss the quantization in the first-to-classical approximation just like we do for the bosons.

Comment: @Luboš Motl: If something appears in an exponent, this does not necessarily mean that this "something" is "a real commuting c-number" - we know how to define exponents of, e.g., supernumbers. Your caveat "at least formally" can make pretty much any statement correct, "at least formally", but it strips any content from any statement. I insist that, strictly speaking, the Lagrangian in question is not a c-number, as it contains nonzero "soul". E.g., in a Grassmann algebra with a finite number of generators the fermionic part of the Lagrangian would vanish if multiplied by all of the generators.

Comment: No, akhmateli, I wrote that that it has to be a real commuting $c$-number because it appears as action in the exponent and be sure it is true. Exponents have to be Grassmann-even and in the path integral, they have to be real for the theory to be unitary i.e. preserve the total probability. Also, it is completely untrue that the word "formally" strips content. Quite on the contrary, if one carefully evaluates the reality and other properties formally, he gets much more accurate a verdict than if he does so informally!

Comment: @Luboš Motl: So it looks like we agree that the Lagrangian is Grassmann-even-valued and Grassmann-real, but it's not real-number-valued.

Comment: Luboš Motl, how can be sure the mass term is real in dirac Lagrangian? Dirac spinors are grassmann even variables, therefore [ψψbar]† = -ψψbar,we obtain the opposite sign of the original mass term so it's not hermitian? ps: for two fermionic field A and B, (AB)† = -B†A†.

Answer (score 4):

Let us sort out some terminology issues first. If the fermionic fields in your Lagrangian are Grassmanian, that means that the Lagrangian is classical, i.e. second quantization has not been performed yet. You can write a classical Lagrangian using c-number fermionic fields, but, as far as I understand, it is generally recognized now that one should use the classical Lagrangian with Grassmanian fermionic fields.

I also ran into the issue that you describe some time ago. I may be mistaken, but my conclusion was that indeed, the Lagrangian is not real, for the reasons that you give in your question. On the other hand, it is not obvious why this is necessarily bad.

EDIT: Maybe, to avoid ambiguity, I should have written that the Lagrangian is not real-valued

Comment: Your conclusion is in line with my friend's conclusion.  I feel very disconcerted by this.  If I compute the stress-energy tensor by following Noether's theorem, doesn't this mean the energy is also not real-valued?  What's going on???

Comment: Yes, I may be mistaken, but it looks like the energy is not real-valued either. But again, why is this necessarily bad? We are not used to it, but there a lot of things in physics we are not used to. Remember, the classical Lagrangian (and the classical energy) are only some interim structures in QED.

Comment: Don't get freaked out--- the energy is not real valued, but the expectation value in any state is real valued. You have to remember that these grassman things are classical limits of quantum fields, and the states are constructed by using the ring elements, and the end result, when you compute some amplitude or expection value is always real.