# Are statistical fields commutative?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, operators, path-integral, wick-rotation

In both statistical field theory and quantum field theory one computes average values / time ordered expectation values of functionals of fields with the path integral. I have two related questions:

1. Is it the path integral alone that make quantum fields non-commutative or are other constraints also required?
2. Are statistical fields non-commutative?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48030/2451

Answer (score 1):

1) It's exactly the opposite of what you said - in the Hamiltonian operator formalism, the fields are non-commutative; the Lagrangian path integral is an equivalent reformulation of the problem in which the fields *are* commutative.  Field ordering doesn't matter in the path integral; the original "non-commuting-ness" effectively gets absorbed into the integration measure.

2) I guess it depends on exactly what you mean by "statistical fields," but nope, anything that goes into a path integral is commutative.

Comment: 1)Ordering does matter inside the path integral in the case of equal times: If we evaluate the equal time commutator of the momentum conjugate with the field inside the path integral, the answer is nonzero.  2)By statistical field I mean a field  which has no time dependence.

Comment: @Luke, no all the fields inside the path integral all commuting c-number fields.  There aren't any commutators inside of path integrals.  The fields in the path integral correspond to *normal-ordered* particle creation/annihilation operators, so there is no ordering ambiguity.

Also, statistical partition functions for quantum many-body systems have *imaginary* time dependence, although classical many-body systems do not.

Comment: +1, with the caveat that Grassmann numbers are anticommutative.

Comment: @knzhou Good point. I guess that means this answer's wrong, but I'm too lazy to fix it.