# Supersymmetry transformations as coordinate transformations

Tags: supersymmetry, fermions, supergravity, grassmann-numbers, superspace-formalism

Usually, a supersymmetry transformation is carried out on bosonic and fermionic fields which are functions of the coordinates (or on a superfield which is a function of real and fermionic coordinates). But, is it possible to interpret supersymmetry transformations as coordinate transformations on the set of coordinates $(x^0,\ldots,x^N,\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_M)$?

The problem I see is that the coordinates would transform something like $x^\mu\rightarrow x^\mu+\theta\sigma\bar{\theta}$ which is no longer a real (or complex) number, but a commuting Grassmann number. Can one make sens of a coordinate position no longer being a real number?

Edit: To clarify, this is NOT about confusion in what happens when adding real numbers with commuting grassmann numbers in general. That the lagrangian in QFT for example is not a real number, but a commuting grassmann number, is fine. What I am confused about is really how to make sense of *coordinates* that are grassmannian. Coordinates are supposed to describe a position in spacetime/on a manifold, and it seems to me that it is essential that a position is a standard real number.

Comment: what kind of mathematical object is the sum of a real/complex number and a grassmannian? It is obviously closed under sum, and apparently under multiplication, but probably not a full fledged field, since no inverse

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40746/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: @Qmechanic: No it is not a duplicate of this (but it is essentially the same as the unanswered comment in the first reply). I have edited my post to clarify!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments to the question (v3):

1. Recall that a [supernumber](http://planetmath.org/supernumber) $z=z_B+z_S$ consists of a *body* $z_B$ (which always belongs to $\mathbb{C}$) and a *soul* $z_S$ (which only belongs to $\mathbb{C}$ if it is zero), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40746/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. An observable/measurable quantity can only consist of ordinary numbers (belonging to $\mathbb{C}$). It does not make sense to measure a soul-valued output in an actual experiment.
3. Souls are [indeterminates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_%28variable%29) that appear in intermediate formulars, but are integrated (or  differentiated) out in the final result.
4. In a superspace formulation of a field theory, a Grasmann-even spacetime coordinates $x^{\mu}$ in superspace is promoted to a supernumber, and is not necessarily an ordinary number.
5. A supersymmetry-translation of a Grasmann-even spacetime coordinate $x^{\mu}$ only changes the soul (but not the body) of $x^{\mu}$.
6. Note that in the mathematical [definition](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/supermanifold) of a [supermanifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermanifold), the focus of the theory is not on spacetime coordinates per se, but (very loosely speaking) rather on certain algebras of functions of spacetime. See also e.g. Refs. 1-3 for details.

References:

1. Pierre Deligne and John W. Morgan, *Notes on Supersymmetry (following Joseph Bernstein).* In *Quantum Fields and Strings: A Course for Mathematicians,* Vol. 1, American Mathematical Society (1999) 41–97.
2. V.S. Varadarajan, *Supersymmetry for Mathematicians: An Introduction,* Courant Lecture Notes 11, 2004.
3. C. Sachse, *A Categorical Formulation of Superalgebra and Supergeometry,* [arXiv:0802.4067](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.4067).