# Convert Grassmann numbers to real numbers

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

We know Grassmann numbers are complex numbers. Hence Grassmann integrals are also complex. How can we convert a Grassmann integral into real one, ie is there any transformation of converting complex Grassmann numbers to real grassmann numbers?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Please note that clarity helps people understand your question. Part of good clarity is proper English punctuation, such as using a space between sentences. I edited this question to fix the punctuation. Please do pay attention to these important details in future posts.

Comment: In what sense are Grassman numbers complex numbers? I'm pretty sure these are not the same thing. I think Grassman numbers are more like the Fermionic $a^\dagger$ operator. Perhaps you can convert path integrals involving Grassman numbers into expressions involving complex numbers.

Comment: This is way above me, but on the off chance it helps, (and you probably are aware) Wikipedia calls them c-numbers, which was very confusing to me till I read that this was Dirac's notation, I would have  automatically taken c-numbers to mean complex numbers until I read that Dirac meant classical numbers. Wikipedia is not well written in this section, imo.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number

Grassmann numbers are more like matrices than actual numbers.

Comment: The question is unclear: Grassmann number aren't real number, Grassmann integrals aren't actually integrals (complex or real), so what are you actually trying to ask?

Answer (score 2):

Comments to the question (v3):

1. A [Grassmann-odd number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number) is *not* a [complex number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number). It is a complex [*supernumber*](http://planetmath.org/supernumber) $z=x+iy$, which can be decomposed in real and imaginary *supernumbers,* cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40746/2451)  and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/187320/2451) Phys.SE posts.
2. The [Berezin integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berezin_integral) $\int\! d\theta~f(\theta)$ over supernumbers is an ordinary complex number $c=a+ib\in\mathbb{C}$, which can be decomposed in real and imaginary numbers.