# D'Alembert Operator on Fermionic Field in Path Integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, fermions, yang-mills, grassmann-numbers

I am learning the Faddeev–Popov path integral formlism with Schwartz's QFT textbook. In the section 25.4.2 "BRST invariance", I came across the Lagrangian as:
$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu}^{2}+\left(D_{\mu} \phi_{i}^{\star}\right)\left(D_{\mu} \phi_{i}\right)-m^{2} \phi_{i}^{\star} \phi_{i}-\frac{1}{2 \xi}\left(\partial_{\mu} A_{\mu}\right)^{2}-\bar{c} \square c$$
And it says the equation of motion of the fermionic fields satisify:
$$\square c=\square \bar{c}=0$$
I am curious and surprised with **the derivative of the fermionc field**(which certainly is a grassmann-valued function with respect to space-time coordinates.)
But the whole Schwartz's textbook doesn't mention how to define the derivative of the grassmann-valued function with respect to certain **real-valued variables**(There is indeed a section about Grassmann Algebra, but it doesn't introduce how to define this!).

So my question is it correct to define the derivative as similar to ordinary calculus:
$$c'(x)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{c(x+\epsilon)-c(x)}{\epsilon}$$
I suspect that the above "definition" is  not well-defined.
Could anyone give a physical-intution explanation to the derivative, or any reference to the strange derivative?

Answer (score 0):

OP is asking a good question. However, the mathematical foundation of [supernumber](https://planetmath.org/supernumber)-valued fields is quite intricate, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40746/2451) Phys.SE post. The first issue is that a [Grassmann-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number) is an [indeterminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_(variable)) that does not actually take a value!  For a full rigorous explanation, consider to consult a textbook in [supermathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermathematics) or to ask on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)/[MO.SE](https://mathoverflow.net/) instead. The upshot is that differentiation of supernumber-valued fields do make sense when cast in the appropriate mathematical setting.

As always when considering a [path integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) (whose rigorous mathematical definition  is an open problem in general) physicists often envision spacetime as a continuum limit of a discrete spacetime lattice. Spacetime derivatives of supernumber-valued fields then get replaced by their corresponding [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference). Whether the continuum limit makes sense is an open problem not just for supernumber-valued field theories.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean for convenience we might treat the contiunous limits as the lattice finte-difference expression, such as a discrete matrix formalism. Maybe I shouldn't dig into much the details of the mathematics.

Comment: I updated the answer.