# Why reasonable observables are made of an even number of fermion fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, fermions, observables, grassmann-numbers

On Michele Maggiore book on QFT (page 91) is stated, out of nothing, that "observables are made of an even number of fermionic operator" and similar sentences is in Peskin book (page 56).
Is there any physical and mathematical reason for that?

Comment: It is the so-called (fermionic) parity superselection.

Comment: @TobiasFunke I think your comment deserves to be elaborated into a full answer, of course, at your convenience.

Comment: @hyportnex I agree, but I don't have much time right now. Perhaps later. Also, I couldn't find a good (textbook) reference except one or two lecture notes.

Answer (score 1):

One explanation is that on one hand an observable should be a quantity/operator that could take a value in a measurement in the form of (a tuple of) ordinary numbers.

On the other hand (an odd product of) fermionic operators is Grassmann-odd. A [Grassmann-odd number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number) is an [indeterminate/variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_(variable)), which has no value, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40746/2451) Phys.SE post.